# Highlighting rows in excel based on detecting number patterns across multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I was wondering if there would be a way to highlight multiple rows based off of two distinct number patterns detected across  the rows. Only one number either a 0 or 1 will appear in each cell but I am trying to detect the pattern across the row in three different cells like in the picture I provided. The two patterns I am looking to highlight are 0 0 0 and 0 1 0.

I'm open to a formula or VBA code I'm just lost as to how to structure this.

Comment: What is the pattern(s)?

Comment: I attached an image as an example but forgot to mention the patterns! The patterns are 0 0 0 and 0 1 0.

Comment: (...if I didn't know any better, I'd say you're tracking a wire... :P)

Comment: Have you tried Conditional Formatting? `=(OR(AND($D2=0,$E2=0,$F2=0),AND($D2=0,$E2=1,$F2=0))`?  Or, `=OR(SUM($D2:$F2)=0),AND($D2=0,$E2=1,$F2=0))`

Comment: I was wondering if someone would catch the reference, Conditional formatting was my first guess how to go about solving this issue and your first formula looks like what I was aiming for but I keep getting an error "the formula is missing an opening or closing parenthesis" and I can't for the life of me figure out why after trying multiple combinations of parenthesis.

Comment: `=OR(SUM($D2:$F2)=0,AND($D2=0,$E2=1,$F2=0))`

Comment: You nailed it Scott. that last formula you posted works wonderfully, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add a formula in col H

```
$D2&$E2&$F2
```

Then use conditional formatting. You want Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cells>More Rules>Use a formula.. and use a formula like `=OR($H2="000",$H2="010")`

and apply it to your whole sheet (starting on row 2, or adjust the formula)

Comment: Why do the helper column on such a simple formula: `=OR($D2&$E2&$F2="000",$D2&$E2&$F2="010")`?

Comment: People struggle with the formulas in conditional formatting, especially when they haven't used them before. I find its best to keep that field as simple as possible. Also that field doesn't go multi-line.